# Internal 2.5" HDD of old laptop connected via external USB SATA enclosure but no letter assigned, no way to access it

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, usb-storage, enclosures

I open disk management in windows 7 and it is listed as a basic drive online with 75GB RAW (It is actually FAT), 243MB Active Primary partition and the bulk in a separate partition.

If I right click on either I can only select delete volume. I want to copy over the data from the drive.

How do I access it?

Comment: What OS was the old laptop using, and what filesystem was the disk using (FAT, NTFS, maybe ext or HFS if it was linux or mac) ?

Comment: It was FAT originally.

Comment: I might look into using a Linux Live CD to see if you can access the drive.